# HTML Knockout radio button to call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, radio-button

I am using knockout to loop around an array to display a list of radio buttons with labels, and I want it so that whenever a radio button is selected it then calls function `onInputChange`.

My current code is:

```
<p data-bind="foreach:properties">
    <br>
    <input name="filter" type="radio" data-bind="checked:$root.sortType, event:$root.onInputChange">
    <label for="filter" data-bind="text:id"></label>
    <br>
</p>
```

Comment: can you post fiddle and what is problem with current code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do below

```
<input name="filter" type="radio" data-bind="checked:$root.sortType, event: { change: $root.onInputChange}">
```

Comment: thank you so much, i tried different combinations and experimenting with attached event - i had running initially so that the radio button wasnt selected but the function was called. this now works as intended, thank you again.

Comment: You are most welcome and all the best for future tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```js
var model = function() {
  var sortType = ko.observable("Two");
  var properties = ko.observableArray([{id: "One"}, {id: "Two"}, {id: "Three"}]);

  function onInputChange(item) {
    alert("changed to: " + item.id);
  }

  return {
    sortType: sortType,
    properties: properties,
    onInputChange: onInputChange
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p data-bind="foreach:properties">
  <br>
  <input name="filter" type="radio"
      data-bind="value: id, 
         checked:$parent.sortType, 
         event: {change : $parent.onInputChange }">
  <label for="filter" data-bind="text:id"></label>
  <br>
</p>
```